# Why do my containers size bigger than the screen size that causes the SingleChildScrollView() to scroll when the keyboard is down?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am building a RegisterPage in flutter and I devided my scaffold into two containers. One for the top half and the other for the bottom half so that the logo/headline can be in the top half and the form be in the bottom half.

Now I noticed after testing on android that the keyboard overlaps the input fields. So I added a SingleChildScrollView() view to fix this. But there is a problem. The content appears to be too big and you can now always scroll even when the keyboard is down. I added a video to demonstrate what I mean.

I think that this space is responsible for that

[image]

It looks like that space is reserved for the android navigation bar. How do I remove that? Or how can I size my containers in such a way so that they account for that? Just to be clear the thing I want to know most is how I can stop my SingleChildScrollView() scrolling when the keyboard is down, which is probably cause by the containers being to big.

**the_register_page.dart**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = Provider.of<AuthenticationProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: Center(
        child: ScrollConfiguration(
          behavior: ScrollBehaviourWithoutGlow(),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                  child: _buildLogo(),
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                  child: _buildRegisterForm(authenticationProvider),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Notice that I used the SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]); in my main.dart.

**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);

    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<PreferencesProvider>(
            create: (_) => PreferencesProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthenticationProvider>(
            create: (_) => AuthenticationProvider()),
        Provider<GroupProvider>(create: (_) => GroupProvider()),
        Provider<UserProvider>(
          create: (_) => UserProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: Consumer<PreferencesProvider>(
        builder: (context, preferences, _) => MaterialApp(
          home: TheSplashPage(),
          routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
            TheGroupPage.routeName: (BuildContext context) => TheGroupPage(),
            TheSettingsPage.routeName: (BuildContext context) =>
                TheSettingsPage(),
            TheProfilePage.routeName: (BuildContext context) =>
                TheProfilePage(),
            TheGroupCreationPage.routeName: (BuildContext context) =>
                TheGroupCreationPage(),
          },
          theme: preferences.isDarkMode
              ? DarkTheme.themeData
              : LightTheme.themeData,
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Since this post didn't get any answers I decided to upload a video to show what I mean. Here is the video. As you can see you are able to swipe even when the keyboard is down which is not what I want.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rm91KMFqs60

**Edit**

This is tested on a android emulator

[image]

And my android device a Lenovo P2 with android 7

**Edit**

I can confirm that this bottom area is the cause. I looked at the pixel height on my pc screen and subtracted that from the container and now I can't scroll when the keyboard is down which is what I want.

So I would like to remove this area or get it's height any idea how?

Comment: Is the navigation bar auto-hide behaviour set by your app or by your device settings? What device and Android version do you use? Can you replicate that in an emulator?

Comment: I added the info to my post. I setup the hide behaviour in my main.dart. I tested it both on my own device a Lenovo P2 with android 7 and a Pixel 2 with android 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close. Setting the `SystemChrome` color to transparent just makes them see-through but won't draw your app over top of the navigation or status bars. The fix is a 2 step process.

1. Set `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUIOverlay.top])` to display only the notification bar or `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([])` to display your app in full screen.
2. In your `Scaffold` set the `resizeToBottomInset` property to `false` when you want the screen to display over top of the bottom system UI overlay and to `true` when the keyboard is up.

Full code example:

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Display your app in full-screen mode
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  // Show the notification bar but not the navigation bar
  // SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  bool resizeToAvoidBottom;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Do not avoid bottom by default, this allows the display to paint over
    // where the Android button bar would be.
    resizeToAvoidBottom = false;
  }

  void setResize(bool resize) {
    setState(() {
      resizeToAvoidBottom = resize;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2;

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: resizeToAvoidBottom,
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Placeholder(
                fallbackHeight: height,
              ),
              Container(
                height: height,
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      // Text fields update the resize property so that you
                      // can still scroll the display when the keyboard is up
                      // You will need to change when setResize(false) is
                      // called to suit the needs of your app
                      TextField(
                        onTap: () {
                          setResize(true);
                        },
                        onSubmitted: (str) {
                          setResize(false);
                        },
                      ),
                      TextField(
                        onTap: () {
                          setResize(true);
                        },
                        onSubmitted: (str) {
                          setResize(false);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I also had the `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);` it's in the question. But just using that didn't completely remove the ui overlays so I combined it with the SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle. I'll have a look later today if removing the SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle will fix the problem but I don't think so.

Comment: Just tested it and the problem still remains

Comment: Seems pretty hacky, and I did think about this myself. Is there no elegant solution to this?

Comment: As of right now, no. As @vnztms mentioned, this is currently a bug in the framework and an issue is opened on the github repo for this behavior.

Comment: Gues this will have to do for now

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a current [Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47683).

There is workaround which you could use, which is setting `extendxBody: true` in your Scaffold.
But if it is not extremely critical I would wait for the fix to be deployed.

To clarify: My answer is about the empty space at the bottom.

Comment: extendbody: true does not the empty space at the bottom. It's still there

Comment: I am currently at work, so I couldn't look into my code to find the correct parameter. I thought it was this one. I will look into it when I get home ;). In the bug I linked they mentioned the following: 'resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,' , maybe this works?

Comment: So I just checked in my personal project. When I set " resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false " in my scaffold, the body is extends to the bottom. But like I said, use it with caution, as this is just a workaround ;)

Comment: Yes but when the keyboard pops up you won't be able to see the input field because it stops the SingleChildScrollView() from working.

Comment: yeah well, I assume that, because of the issue, you currently can't have both.  As I understand you want both areas to be exactly half of the screen and not scrollable if the keyboard isn't visible? So this is merely a cosmetical problem? If so you could maybe just ignore it for the time being, you could revert your flutter version, on the other you could make your layout more dynamic by not using the rather fixed heights for your containers.

Comment: I found a better solution for you: keep everything you have and simply subtract kBottomNavigationBarHeight from the screenHeight. It is a constant in Flutter. I guess that should solve your problem until the issue is fixed.